# MS SQL 2008 R2 invalid prefix & suffix error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 for my database. But when i am trying to edit table it is showing me this error. However i am able to edit it via query but if i want to edit directly from table it is showing this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common issue for 2008R2, typically the suggestion is to either use 2012 SSMS or to simply edit via query commands.

I know that isn't really helpful toward your problem but making DDL/DML changes via query is probably a good habit/skill you should cultivate rather than relying on the GUI editor.

Perhaps it's for the best!